# Using both Entity Framework and SqlConnection?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework

## Background

I'm working on a project which contains both legacy code and Entity Framework code. I was advised to use a specific dataservice method to operate on a record from the database. The record was retrieved via Entity Framework, and I passed the PK into the dataservice function to perform the operation.

## Preconditions for success and failure

**If the network was up**, both DB calls (entity and SQL) would succeed. **If the network went down**, then came back up and this code was executed, then it would retrieve the locked records with entity framework but then fail with the `SqlException` below.

This got me thinking, what is going on here that might cause the `SqlConnection` to fail despite EF being able to make the connection.

## Code Samples

A code sample follows:

```
public void HandleNetworkBecomesAvailable() {
    _entityFrameworkDataService.ReleaseRecords();
}
```

EntityFrameworkDataService.cs

```
    public void ReleaseRecords()
    {
        using (var context = new Entities()) // using EntityConnection
        {
            var records = context.Records.Where(
                record => record.IsLocked).ToList();

            foreach (var record in records)
            {
                 _sqlConnectionDataService.UnlockRecord(record.ID);
            }
        }
    }
```

SqlConnectionDataService.cs

```
    public void UnlockRecord(int recordId)
    {
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Sqlconnection"].ConnectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();

            using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
            {
                command.CommandText = @"UPDATE [Records] SET [IsLocked] = 0";
                //etc

                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
```

App.config

```
<add name="EntityConnection" connectionString="metadata=res://*/FooDatabase.csdl|res://*/FooDatabase.ssdl|res://*/FooDatabase.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=RemoteServer;initial catalog=FooDatabase;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
<add name="SqlConnection" connectionString="Server=RemoteServer;Database=FooDatabase;Trusted_Connection=True" />
```

Now, after discussing with my coworkers, I ended up moving the logic into the entity framework dataservice and doing the work there. But I'm still not quite sure why the connection kept failing.

Edit: The actual error is:

> An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)
>
> Inner Exception:
>
> The network path was not found

But Entity Framework is using the same network path, as can be seen in the two connection strings in the App.config.

Comment: What was the actual message text of the exception? And was there an inner-exception?

Comment: It seems that the server cannot be reached, are you sure the connection string used is OK?

Comment: The exception is basically saying it can't connect to the sql server using the connection string you have provided. If you get that intermittently it is indicative of networking problems rather than anything in the code. If you get it consistently then the connection string you are using is wrong.

Comment: Yelling at people will not help you to get the answer

Comment: I don't know how else to stress something I reiterated 3 times in the op.

Comment: No need to be upset :-)  If I remember correctly, EF uses special connection strings which might not work properly for "regular" data connections.  Show us your connection string (mask out sensitive info of course).

Comment: I added the two connection strings along with some code that more closely resembles what we're actually doing. You'll see that the `EntityConnection` and the `SqlConnection` are in fact identical.

Comment: You are missing the provider for the second conn string

Comment: @CarlosMuñoz: These are the exact connection strings, with sensitive data masked out, as I have copied from out our project. These do in fact work when the network is up when the application is running. Please refer to the [SQL Server 2008 Connection Strings](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008/) to see that these are formatted correctly for the non-entity version.

Comment: Why not simply use the DbConnection object of your DbContext/ObjectContext?

Comment: Could you be benefiting from entity framework's new resiliency, where it retries transparently? If the error is intermittent, you won't even know it retried, whereas ADO.net is letting you know it fails as soon as it fails. Just checking...

Comment: Moved comment to answer

Answer (score 1):

Could you be benefiting from entity framework's new resiliency, where it retries transparently? If the error is intermittent, you won't even know it retried, whereas ADO.net is letting you know it fails as soon as it fails. Just checking...

Comment: I am inclined to believe this as I know Entity Framework does some form of custom connection management. Could you provide any links that might provide some evidence that this is occurring?

Comment: My only concern is that the sql query happens only if the entity framework query succeeds, which means the connection would have to be available.

Comment: What value do you set for Multiple active result sets?

Comment: No, EF only has connection resilience if you explicitly configure it to do so.

Comment: @reckface MARS is set to true for EF

Comment: It remains a mystery then. Is this still happening? If so, try matching the ADO.Net connection with the provider section of the EF connection string. For example, for example: enable MARS there too. And **as a last resort**, use the newer property names in your ADO.net connection string. So DataSource instead of server, initial catalog...

Comment: I just reread the conditions for failure - when the connection was down and returns EF works but ADO.net fails. This sounds more like a connection pooling issue. Are you using this anywhere: SqlConnection.ClearPools; are you using your connections in a narrow scope? remember EF will dispose of the context/connection correctly in a using statement, ADO.net will do the same as long as that's also in a using. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6338834/intermittent-sql-exception-network-related-or-instance-specific-error)